# Invalid Object Name - SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

when executing the following stored procedure I get Invalid Object Name dbo.Approved. The object dbo.Approved does exist, so presumably this is something to do with the way i pass the table name in as the parameter?

I should also add that i get the error either by executing the procedure via .NET, or from within SMSS.

```
 @tableName as nvarchar(100)
AS
 BEGIN

EXEC('

UPDATE T1
SET T1.NPTid = dbo.Locations.NPT_ID
FROM '  + '[' + @tableName +  '] As T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations  ON T1.Where_Committed = dbo.Locations.Location_Name
')

END
```

Edit after receiving help from Joe and JNK the sproc is now this  but i get the error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Updater, Line 14  

Incorrect syntax near 'QUOTENAME'.
```

new sproc

```
@tableName as nvarchar(100),
@schemaName as nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN  



EXEC('
--Update NPT
UPDATE T1
SET T1.NPTid = dbo.Locations.NPT_ID
FROM '  + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' As T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations  ON T1.Where_Committed = dbo.Locations.Location_Name
')

END
```

Comment: how are you passing the table name in as a parameter? "dbo.Approved" or "Approved"

Comment: Yes, You can ignore the Alter Proc bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the square brackets in you string, your table reference turns into `[dbo.Approved]` which is not valid. The reference should be `[dbo].[Approved]` instead.

You might want to consider passing schema name and table name as two separate parameters.

It would also be better to use the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function instead of hard coding the square brackets.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

set @sql = N'UPDATE T1
SET T1.NPTid = dbo.Locations.NPT_ID
FROM '  + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' As T1
INNER JOIN dbo.Locations  ON T1.Where_Committed = dbo.Locations.Location_Name
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Like This? FROM [dbo].'+  QUOTENAME(@tableName) +  '] As T1

Comment: @Doozer - you don't need the closing bracket before `AS T1`

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli - I would +2 if I could :)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Updater, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'QUOTENAME'.
Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @Doozer1979: Build your string into a variable, like `@sql nvarchar(1000)`, then `exec (@sql)`. I'll update my answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you use brackets for the three-part-name, you need to have brackets around each section but not the period, i.e.:

`[dbo].[Approved]`

If you pass `dbo.Approved` as your parameter, your Dynamic SQL is reading it as `[dbo.Approved]` which would only work if you had a table named that (i.e. the dbo. is part of the table name not the schema).

Change it to:

`'...[dbo].[' + @tablename + ']...`

And just pass `Approved` as the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Your wrapping the id too early so '[' + @tableName +  '] is getting translated to [dbo.approved] when it should be [dbo].[Approved]

Answer (score 1):

Table names and column names are actually sysname (which is, as I recall an `NVARCHAR(128)` or `NVARCHAR(256)` - off the top of my head I don't quite remember)

Also, You are vulnerable to a SQL Injection Attack. You should validate that `@tableName` is a real table by checking it against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Finally, just to be absolutely sure, in case the real table has some odd characters in it, you should use `QUOTENAME(@tableName)` to fully escape the table name.

Comment: the brackets are the issue, not the data type :)

Comment: Cheers. I'm aware that it's vulnerable to SQL injection, but it's just a helper app that will run on only one machine, by me.